# Search table based on linked text field from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Not being an SQL wiz at all, browsing through the results here, I was unable to find a proper solution, although the problem itself is fairly simple.

Two tables:

- products

  - id
  - title
- strings

  - id
  - language_en

An entry in `products` may look like this:

```
id = 1
title = 10
```

Corresponding entry in `strings`:

```
id = 10
language_en = "myProduct"
```

Where as the number in `products.title` contains the id of a corresponding entry in `strings`.

I want to search `products` for a certain title, but those titles are stored in `strings` (because of multi-language capacities).

This is what i came up with:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p JOIN strings s ON p.title LIKE s.language_en WHERE s.language_en LIKE "myProduct"
```

Unfortunately, this does not yield any proper results. Obviously i have trouble understanding the concept behind the join, but even reading some articles on the concept does not get me there. It's not my pair of shoes.

Comment: Is the title actually 'test'?

Comment: This is just a breakdown of the actual structure and query used. I tested with proper data. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sql  condition may be wrong i think, i modified that sql.

```
select p.* FROM products p JOIN strings s ON p.title = s.id  and   s.language_en = "Product name"
```

you can execute and see the result.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, these sql running properly or not?

Comment: God, i feel so blind now. You're right. I think this is it. Let me test it properly, i'll get back to this in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` is wrong - it's comparing `p.title` to `s.language_en` instead of `s.id` which you described should match it.

Also note that when used without a wildcard, the `like` operator is essentially equivalent to `=`, and it may make the code easier to read if you use it directly:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM   products p 
JOIN   strings s ON p.title = s.id 
WHERE  s.language_en = 'myProduct'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. As for the `LIKE` operator - i use wildcards actually, but left them out in the example above.